# Changing line width of some lines out of a group of multiple lines using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data file structure:

```
Form    invivo  invitro Time      Fa.IVIVC      Fabs
1    1   0.00000  0.00000 0.00 Fa = m*Fd + c  26.93499
2    1  99.99999 57.00039 0.67 Fa = m*Fd + c  74.71297
3    1 100.00000 79.19487 1.33 Fa = m*Fd + c  93.31648
4    1 100.00000 89.94020 2.00 Fa = m*Fd + c 102.32326
5    1 100.00000 94.48189 2.67 Fa = m*Fd + c 106.13013
6    1 100.00000 96.53548 3.33 Fa = m*Fd + c 107.85145
```

I have pasted the entire data frame at the end of this question using dput() so that you can reproduce my example. My example assumes you assign the dput output to the object df.

I want to plot column "invivo" as Y-axis against "invitro" as the X-axis by means of points colored by column "Form" to which I assign appropriate labels in the gpplot2 call (see below). I then overlay on this plot a series of lines specified by a subset of column "Fabs" against "invitro" with linetype determined by column "Fa.IVIVC". Here are the commands I used to create the plot followed by the result:

```
library(ggplot2)
> ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = invitro, y = invivo, 
+            colour = factor(Form, labels = c("Fast", "Medium", "Slow")))) +
+            geom_line(data = subset(df, Form == 3 & `Fa.IVIVC` != "Sigmoid" & 
+            `Fa.IVIVC` != "DWeibull"), aes(x = invitro, y = Fabs, linetype = `Fa.IVIVC`)) +
+            labs(title = "Plot", colour = "Formulation")  + 
+            scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
+            theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
+            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image]

**Can someone tell me how to manually change the line width of two (out of eight) of the lines in order to make them stand out more?** Thank you.

```
> dput(df)

structure(list(Form = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), invivo = c(0, 99.99998579, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 13.0348383, 
23.19770255, 95.89812941, 99.94931988, 99.99614995, 99.99979491, 
99.99999186, 99.99999974, 99.99999999, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 0, 2.069875621, 6.072987344, 43.35498005, 96.60344484, 
99.99980946, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 0, 99.99998579, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 13.0348383, 
23.19770255, 95.89812941, 99.94931988, 99.99614995, 99.99979491, 
99.99999186, 99.99999974, 99.99999999, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 0, 2.069875621, 6.072987344, 43.35498005, 96.60344484, 
99.99980946, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 0, 99.99998579, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 13.0348383, 
23.19770255, 95.89812941, 99.94931988, 99.99614995, 99.99979491, 
99.99999186, 99.99999974, 99.99999999, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 0, 2.069875621, 6.072987344, 43.35498005, 96.60344484, 
99.99980946, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 0, 99.99998579, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 13.0348383, 
23.19770255, 95.89812941, 99.94931988, 99.99614995, 99.99979491, 
99.99999186, 99.99999974, 99.99999999, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 0, 2.069875621, 6.072987344, 43.35498005, 96.60344484, 
99.99980946, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 0, 99.99998579, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 13.0348383, 
23.19770255, 95.89812941, 99.94931988, 99.99614995, 99.99979491, 
99.99999186, 99.99999974, 99.99999999, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 0, 2.069875621, 6.072987344, 43.35498005, 96.60344484, 
99.99980946, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 0, 99.99998579, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 13.0348383, 
23.19770255, 95.89812941, 99.94931988, 99.99614995, 99.99979491, 
99.99999186, 99.99999974, 99.99999999, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 0, 2.069875621, 6.072987344, 43.35498005, 96.60344484, 
99.99980946, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 0, 99.99998579, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 13.0348383, 
23.19770255, 95.89812941, 99.94931988, 99.99614995, 99.99979491, 
99.99999186, 99.99999974, 99.99999999, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 0, 2.069875621, 6.072987344, 43.35498005, 96.60344484, 
99.99980946, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 0, 99.99998579, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 13.0348383, 
23.19770255, 95.89812941, 99.94931988, 99.99614995, 99.99979491, 
99.99999186, 99.99999974, 99.99999999, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 0, 2.069875621, 6.072987344, 43.35498005, 96.60344484, 
99.99980946, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 0, 99.99998579, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 13.0348383, 
23.19770255, 95.89812941, 99.94931988, 99.99614995, 99.99979491, 
99.99999186, 99.99999974, 99.99999999, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 0, 2.069875621, 6.072987344, 43.35498005, 96.60344484, 
99.99980946, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 0, 99.99998579, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 13.0348383, 
23.19770255, 95.89812941, 99.94931988, 99.99614995, 99.99979491, 
99.99999186, 99.99999974, 99.99999999, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 0, 2.069875621, 6.072987344, 43.35498005, 96.60344484, 
99.99980946, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 99.99994989, 
99.99994989, 99.99994989), invitro = c(0, 57.00039229, 79.19486901, 
89.94020448, 94.48189406, 96.53547792, 97.6846376, 98.40076271, 
98.8676286, 99.19033157, 99.41366963, 99.56873896, 99.68122405, 
99.86434085, 99.93886517, 99.98592267, 99.99895618, 0, 13.96103106, 
28.91044539, 43.21827297, 55.60380457, 65.56707672, 73.47911752, 
79.47296755, 83.87519276, 87.18727142, 89.64789772, 91.47785689, 
92.90936128, 95.67702506, 97.26097381, 98.86512577, 99.79579063, 
0, 3.232083127, 9.730153549, 18.07219246, 27.12446726, 35.98788691, 
44.41521695, 51.96255092, 58.40744672, 63.94025941, 68.53310823, 
72.25691906, 75.35971576, 81.78318811, 85.74014133, 90.29959282, 
93.32240733, 0, 57.00039229, 79.19486901, 89.94020448, 94.48189406, 
96.53547792, 97.6846376, 98.40076271, 98.8676286, 99.19033157, 
99.41366963, 99.56873896, 99.68122405, 99.86434085, 99.93886517, 
99.98592267, 99.99895618, 0, 13.96103106, 28.91044539, 43.21827297, 
55.60380457, 65.56707672, 73.47911752, 79.47296755, 83.87519276, 
87.18727142, 89.64789772, 91.47785689, 92.90936128, 95.67702506, 
97.26097381, 98.86512577, 99.79579063, 0, 3.232083127, 9.730153549, 
18.07219246, 27.12446726, 35.98788691, 44.41521695, 51.96255092, 
58.40744672, 63.94025941, 68.53310823, 72.25691906, 75.35971576, 
81.78318811, 85.74014133, 90.29959282, 93.32240733, 0, 57.00039229, 
79.19486901, 89.94020448, 94.48189406, 96.53547792, 97.6846376, 
98.40076271, 98.8676286, 99.19033157, 99.41366963, 99.56873896, 
99.68122405, 99.86434085, 99.93886517, 99.98592267, 99.99895618, 
0, 13.96103106, 28.91044539, 43.21827297, 55.60380457, 65.56707672, 
73.47911752, 79.47296755, 83.87519276, 87.18727142, 89.64789772, 
91.47785689, 92.90936128, 95.67702506, 97.26097381, 98.86512577, 
99.79579063, 0, 3.232083127, 9.730153549, 18.07219246, 27.12446726, 
35.98788691, 44.41521695, 51.96255092, 58.40744672, 63.94025941, 
68.53310823, 72.25691906, 75.35971576, 81.78318811, 85.74014133, 
90.29959282, 93.32240733, 0, 57.00039229, 79.19486901, 89.94020448, 
94.48189406, 96.53547792, 97.6846376, 98.40076271, 98.8676286, 
99.19033157, 99.41366963, 99.56873896, 99.68122405, 99.86434085, 
99.93886517, 99.98592267, 99.99895618, 0, 13.96103106, 28.91044539, 
43.21827297, 55.60380457, 65.56707672, 73.47911752, 79.47296755, 
83.87519276, 87.18727142, 89.64789772, 91.47785689, 92.90936128, 
95.67702506, 97.26097381, 98.86512577, 99.79579063, 0, 3.232083127, 
9.730153549, 18.07219246, 27.12446726, 35.98788691, 44.41521695, 
51.96255092, 58.40744672, 63.94025941, 68.53310823, 72.25691906, 
75.35971576, 81.78318811, 85.74014133, 90.29959282, 93.32240733, 
0, 57.00039229, 79.19486901, 89.94020448, 94.48189406, 96.53547792, 
97.6846376, 98.40076271, 98.8676286, 99.19033157, 99.41366963, 
99.56873896, 99.68122405, 99.86434085, 99.93886517, 99.98592267, 
99.99895618, 0, 13.96103106, 28.91044539, 43.21827297, 55.60380457, 
65.56707672, 73.47911752, 79.47296755, 83.87519276, 87.18727142, 
89.64789772, 91.47785689, 92.90936128, 95.67702506, 97.26097381, 
98.86512577, 99.79579063, 0, 3.232083127, 9.730153549, 18.07219246, 
27.12446726, 35.98788691, 44.41521695, 51.96255092, 58.40744672, 
63.94025941, 68.53310823, 72.25691906, 75.35971576, 81.78318811, 
85.74014133, 90.29959282, 93.32240733, 0, 57.00039229, 79.19486901, 
89.94020448, 94.48189406, 96.53547792, 97.6846376, 98.40076271, 
98.8676286, 99.19033157, 99.41366963, 99.56873896, 99.68122405, 
99.86434085, 99.93886517, 99.98592267, 99.99895618, 0, 13.96103106, 
28.91044539, 43.21827297, 55.60380457, 65.56707672, 73.47911752, 
79.47296755, 83.87519276, 87.18727142, 89.64789772, 91.47785689, 
92.90936128, 95.67702506, 97.26097381, 98.86512577, 99.79579063, 
0, 3.232083127, 9.730153549, 18.07219246, 27.12446726, 35.98788691, 
44.41521695, 51.96255092, 58.40744672, 63.94025941, 68.53310823, 
72.25691906, 75.35971576, 81.78318811, 85.74014133, 90.29959282, 
93.32240733, 0, 57.00039229, 79.19486901, 89.94020448, 94.48189406, 
96.53547792, 97.6846376, 98.40076271, 98.8676286, 99.19033157, 
99.41366963, 99.56873896, 99.68122405, 99.86434085, 99.93886517, 
99.98592267, 99.99895618, 0, 13.96103106, 28.91044539, 43.21827297, 
55.60380457, 65.56707672, 73.47911752, 79.47296755, 83.87519276, 
87.18727142, 89.64789772, 91.47785689, 92.90936128, 95.67702506, 
97.26097381, 98.86512577, 99.79579063, 0, 3.232083127, 9.730153549, 
18.07219246, 27.12446726, 35.98788691, 44.41521695, 51.96255092, 
58.40744672, 63.94025941, 68.53310823, 72.25691906, 75.35971576, 
81.78318811, 85.74014133, 90.29959282, 93.32240733, 0, 57.00039229, 
79.19486901, 89.94020448, 94.48189406, 96.53547792, 97.6846376, 
98.40076271, 98.8676286, 99.19033157, 99.41366963, 99.56873896, 
99.68122405, 99.86434085, 99.93886517, 99.98592267, 99.99895618, 
0, 13.96103106, 28.91044539, 43.21827297, 55.60380457, 65.56707672, 
73.47911752, 79.47296755, 83.87519276, 87.18727142, 89.64789772, 
91.47785689, 92.90936128, 95.67702506, 97.26097381, 98.86512577, 
99.79579063, 0, 3.232083127, 9.730153549, 18.07219246, 27.12446726, 
35.98788691, 44.41521695, 51.96255092, 58.40744672, 63.94025941, 
68.53310823, 72.25691906, 75.35971576, 81.78318811, 85.74014133, 
90.29959282, 93.32240733, 0, 57.00039229, 79.19486901, 89.94020448, 
94.48189406, 96.53547792, 97.6846376, 98.40076271, 98.8676286, 
99.19033157, 99.41366963, 99.56873896, 99.68122405, 99.86434085, 
99.93886517, 99.98592267, 99.99895618, 0, 13.96103106, 28.91044539, 
43.21827297, 55.60380457, 65.56707672, 73.47911752, 79.47296755, 
83.87519276, 87.18727142, 89.64789772, 91.47785689, 92.90936128, 
95.67702506, 97.26097381, 98.86512577, 99.79579063, 0, 3.232083127, 
9.730153549, 18.07219246, 27.12446726, 35.98788691, 44.41521695, 
51.96255092, 58.40744672, 63.94025941, 68.53310823, 72.25691906, 
75.35971576, 81.78318811, 85.74014133, 90.29959282, 93.32240733, 
0, 57.00039229, 79.19486901, 89.94020448, 94.48189406, 96.53547792, 
97.6846376, 98.40076271, 98.8676286, 99.19033157, 99.41366963, 
99.56873896, 99.68122405, 99.86434085, 99.93886517, 99.98592267, 
99.99895618, 0, 13.96103106, 28.91044539, 43.21827297, 55.60380457, 
65.56707672, 73.47911752, 79.47296755, 83.87519276, 87.18727142, 
89.64789772, 91.47785689, 92.90936128, 95.67702506, 97.26097381, 
98.86512577, 99.79579063, 0, 3.232083127, 9.730153549, 18.07219246, 
27.12446726, 35.98788691, 44.41521695, 51.96255092, 58.40744672, 
63.94025941, 68.53310823, 72.25691906, 75.35971576, 81.78318811, 
85.74014133, 90.29959282, 93.32240733), Time = c(0, 0.67, 1.33, 
2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 
0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 
10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 
6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 
4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 
2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 
0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 
10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 
6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 
4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 
2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 
0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 
10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 
6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 
4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 
2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 
0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 
10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 
6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 
4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 
2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 
0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 
10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 
6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 
4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 
2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 
0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 
10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 
6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 
4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 
2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 
0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 
10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 
6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 
4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 0, 0.67, 1.33, 
2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 10, 12, 16, 24, 
0, 0.67, 1.33, 2, 2.67, 3.33, 4, 4.67, 5.33, 6, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 
10, 12, 16, 24), Fa.IVIVC = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("DWeibull", "Fa = Fd", "Fa = m*Fd + c", 
"polyx2", "polyx3", "powerlaw", "Sigmoid", "SWeibull", "Time scale 1", 
"Time scale 2"), class = "factor"), Fabs = c(26.93499216, 74.71296886, 
93.31647577, 102.3232627, 106.1301267, 107.8514496, 108.8146802, 
109.4149394, 109.8062684, 110.0767594, 110.2639624, 110.3939422, 
110.4882277, 110.641717, 110.7041836, 110.7436274, 110.7545521, 
26.93499216, 38.63718911, 51.16785321, 63.16073651, 73.54234296, 
81.89360101, 88.52550802, 93.54957918, 97.23954349, 100.0157422, 
102.0782499, 103.6121296, 104.8120228, 107.1318906, 108.4595634, 
109.8041705, 110.5842579, 26.93499216, 29.64413829, 35.09084918, 
42.08318248, 49.67083858, 57.10019548, 64.16402016, 70.49022832, 
75.89236801, 80.52999567, 84.37974152, 87.50105595, 90.10183364, 
95.4860161, 98.80275149, 102.6245036, 105.1582398, 0, 57.00039229, 
79.19486901, 89.94020448, 94.48189406, 96.53547792, 97.6846376, 
98.40076271, 98.8676286, 99.19033157, 99.41366963, 99.56873896, 
99.68122405, 99.86434085, 99.93886517, 99.98592267, 99.99895618, 
0, 13.96103106, 28.91044539, 43.21827297, 55.60380457, 65.56707672, 
73.47911752, 79.47296755, 83.87519276, 87.18727142, 89.64789772, 
91.47785689, 92.90936128, 95.67702506, 97.26097381, 98.86512577, 
99.79579063, 0, 3.232083127, 9.730153549, 18.07219246, 27.12446726, 
35.98788691, 44.41521695, 51.96255092, 58.40744672, 63.94025941, 
68.53310823, 72.25691906, 75.35971576, 81.78318811, 85.74014133, 
90.29959282, 93.32240733, 0, 70.50447835, 96.02300982, 98.82243596, 
99.57985237, 99.83224857, 99.92919375, 99.96848155, 99.98519963, 
99.99288753, 99.99648008, 99.99819557, 99.99906402, 99.999853, 
99.99997375, 99.99999889, 100, 0, 21.86821136, 62.64275076, 83.43020069, 
91.61448073, 95.12048033, 97.01847895, 98.14482018, 98.82926092, 
99.26289099, 99.5340886, 99.70248132, 99.81071816, 99.9501482, 
99.9866099, 99.99898898, 99.99999343, 0, 6.376662203, 33.21129772, 
57.71307085, 72.54593643, 80.44991197, 85.11225796, 88.14463787, 
90.18710253, 91.58353207, 92.48469374, 93.03463954, 93.36622665, 
93.71057243, 93.75808722, 93.76330413, 93.76332734, 0, 85.43897863, 
96.41023147, 98.60292696, 99.38648274, 99.70817136, 99.85563995, 
99.92570047, 99.96014456, 99.97824987, 99.98785551, 99.99302561, 
99.9959588, 99.99913591, 99.99979511, 99.99998555, 99.99999987, 
0, 35.93136721, 64.82067498, 81.32770255, 89.33896526, 93.27233957, 
95.52120571, 96.93468939, 97.86725864, 98.51674213, 98.96506419, 
99.27211617, 99.48961576, 99.82099549, 99.93627731, 99.99163908, 
99.99984083, 0, 13.56359537, 35.26384187, 54.5683418, 67.93117043, 
76.17184672, 81.40766037, 84.89769958, 87.36608189, 89.23071681, 
90.61604011, 91.61400422, 92.33688852, 93.39590992, 93.68490622, 
93.76120164, 93.7633271, -3.734858599, 98.11558593, 105.8100892, 
103.098802, 100.6902735, 99.35493052, 98.54076048, 98.00910082, 
97.65245063, 97.40129654, 97.22525874, 97.10196412, 97.01198065, 
96.86451038, 96.80414422, 96.76592267, 96.75532221, -3.734858599, 
32.13807789, 62.69125386, 84.32082969, 97.03227093, 103.2085292, 
105.5413274, 105.7928536, 105.1453404, 104.1935427, 103.2281213, 
102.3673602, 101.6091192, 99.93179657, 98.84651217, 97.65438373, 
96.91985905, -3.734858599, 5.20059021, 22.01543783, 41.35062939, 
59.46864426, 74.32100644, 85.7928042, 93.87421248, 99.13528256, 
102.4466828, 104.3498116, 105.3296581, 105.760912, 105.5409361, 
104.6584848, 102.935546, 101.3764816, -7.829154332, 98.13891119, 
102.6750962, 101.2547046, 100.2538484, 99.75104793, 99.45941539, 
99.27457128, 99.15293366, 99.06837985, 99.00964798, 98.96877114, 
98.93907126, 98.89063804, 98.87089782, 98.85842466, 98.85496882, 
-7.829154332, 35.33293502, 67.73270358, 87.50585713, 97.38254122, 
101.420433, 102.6533246, 102.6603132, 102.2559064, 101.7645809, 
101.3127228, 100.9357618, 100.6197217, 99.96433979, 99.56768877, 
99.15358796, 98.90878113, -7.829154332, 3.377571602, 23.66261666, 
45.57203407, 64.53791341, 78.75335477, 88.72896415, 95.08899477, 
98.83482923, 100.9657347, 102.0648218, 102.560815, 102.732557, 
102.4865711, 101.9970047, 101.1821951, 100.5254111, 0, 84.36578127, 
96.62610582, 101.8342357, 103.9253297, 104.8514595, 105.3646665, 
105.6826915, 105.8892912, 106.0317605, 106.1302021, 106.1984762, 
106.2479622, 106.3284514, 106.3611838, 106.3818449, 106.3875664, 
0, 47.21500715, 63.75590158, 75.26043311, 83.50667334, 89.38324247, 
93.68522412, 96.76596308, 98.94262678, 100.536392, 101.6975478, 
102.549008, 103.2081215, 104.465734, 105.1758759, 105.8881852, 
106.2983302, 0, 25.8163831, 40.68030992, 52.52070119, 62.10032081, 
69.78465323, 76.11355987, 81.20537082, 85.21891334, 88.46143461, 
91.02992379, 93.03909356, 94.66721252, 97.91683115, 99.84448999, 
102.001935, 103.3971916, 0, 99.56457982, 99.99802545, 99.99992484, 
99.9999834, 99.99999182, 99.99999453, 99.99999576, 99.99999641, 
99.9999968, 99.99999704, 99.9999972, 99.99999732, 99.99999749, 
99.99999755, 99.99999759, 99.99999761, 0, 19.11114181, 71.01341084, 
95.06173422, 99.42484828, 99.93262192, 99.99056197, 99.99817581, 
99.99949882, 99.99981915, 99.99991739, 99.99995454, 99.99997175, 
99.99998898, 99.99999365, 99.9999964, 99.99999742, 0, 0, 7.282480451, 
33.63646335, 65.74582364, 86.70632144, 95.8867423, 98.85159499, 
99.67345715, 99.90193231, 99.96686136, 99.98701824, 99.9942833, 
99.99906565, 99.99971627, 99.99993312, 99.99997541, 0, 99.886109, 
100.1504034, 100.1506771, 100.15068, 100.1506803, 100.1506803, 
100.1506804, 100.1506804, 100.1506804, 100.1506804, 100.1506804, 
100.1506804, 100.1506804, 100.1506804, 100.1506804, 100.1506804, 
0, 19.5867998, 70.37010127, 95.67671894, 99.78107909, 100.1240798, 
100.1485194, 100.1504311, 100.1506363, 100.1506694, 100.1506767, 
100.1506788, 100.1506796, 100.1506802, 100.1506803, 100.1506804, 
100.1506804, 0, 0.235243688, 8.697988318, 33.12947181, 64.90643719, 
86.93825543, 96.50612289, 99.31146174, 99.9638777, 100.1081475, 
100.1398273, 100.1474151, 100.149556, 100.1505783, 100.15066, 
100.1506776, 100.1506797, 0, 98.42377658, 99.7202431, 99.85721623, 
99.88997474, 99.90180755, 99.90776818, 99.91126546, 99.9134607, 
99.91494041, 99.91594691, 99.91663742, 99.9171341, 99.91793515, 
99.91825853, 99.91846194, 99.91851817, 0, 3.497315952, 63.14218992, 
93.51151385, 98.20640473, 99.24296724, 99.58454984, 99.72537567, 
99.79345734, 99.83170076, 99.8547364, 99.8694627, 99.87975728, 
99.89705477, 99.90562207, 99.91344911, 99.91763636, 0, 0.001560482, 
0.532489605, 12.45115995, 54.99690953, 84.53081847, 94.33616843, 
97.45209375, 98.61212509, 99.13613618, 99.40017939, 99.54612357, 
99.63641308, 99.76395907, 99.81612695, 99.8601966, 99.88254639
)), .Names = c("Form", "invivo", "invitro", "Time", "Fa.IVIVC", 
"Fabs"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -510L))
```

Comment: I tried to use your data, but I had error messages. Could you double check your data stricture?

Comment: I found that if I pasted the data into a text file, I could read the text file with `dget()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I've used `dplyr::mutate()` to add a `Highlight` column to the data you were using for `geom_line()`, then I've used `scale_size_manual()` to specify the width for `TRUE` or `FALSE` in the `Highlight` column. Finally `guides()` is used to hide the legend for the size aesthetic.

```r
df <- dget("~/Desktop/data.txt")

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

line_data <- subset(df, Form == 3 & `Fa.IVIVC` != "Sigmoid" & `Fa.IVIVC` != "DWeibull") %>%
  mutate(Highlight = Fa.IVIVC == "Fa = Fd" | Fa.IVIVC == "powerlaw")

head(line_data)
#>   Form    invivo   invitro Time      Fa.IVIVC     Fabs Highlight
#> 1    3  0.000000  0.000000 0.00 Fa = m*Fd + c 26.93499     FALSE
#> 2    3  2.069876  3.232083 0.67 Fa = m*Fd + c 29.64414     FALSE
#> 3    3  6.072987  9.730154 1.33 Fa = m*Fd + c 35.09085     FALSE
#> 4    3 43.354980 18.072192 2.00 Fa = m*Fd + c 42.08318     FALSE
#> 5    3 96.603445 27.124467 2.67 Fa = m*Fd + c 49.67084     FALSE
#> 6    3 99.999809 35.987887 3.33 Fa = m*Fd + c 57.10020     FALSE

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(
    x = invitro,
    y = invivo,
    colour = factor(Form, labels = c("Fast", "Medium", "Slow"))
  )) +
  geom_line(
    data = line_data,
    aes(x = invitro, y = Fabs, linetype = `Fa.IVIVC`, size = Highlight)
  ) +
  labs(title = "Plot", colour = "Formulation") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
  guides(size = FALSE) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c("TRUE" = 2, "FALSE" = 0.5)) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
  )
```

[image]

You could also use `dplyr::filter()` instead of `subset()` for setting `line_data` if you wished i.e.

```r
line_data <- df %>%
  filter(Form == 3, Fa.IVIVC != 'Sigmoid', Fa.IVIVC != 'DWeibull') %>%
  mutate(Highlight = Fa.IVIVC == "Fa = Fd" | Fa.IVIVC == "powerlaw")
```

Comment: Greg, thank you so much for that. It works and I learned some new things by reading your response. Am I seeing this correctly, it appears that the legend entries for the specific lines int he plot identified with the wider size/thickness are not correspondingly increased in size/thickness? If this is correct, is there some way around that?

Comment: The legend for the `size` aesthetic is separate from the one for the `linetype` aesthetic, hence why you're not seeing a larger size on the `linetype` legend. I've removed the `size` legend. It may be possible to override the `linetype` legend's line size but I think you'll need to start a new question.

Comment: Hi, I just added a new question. Hopefully, it can be addressed swiftly. Thanks again.

Comment: You might want to check out this solution to my follow-up question. It appears to avoid the need for the column "Highlight" altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835435/matching-line-width-in-legend-to-line-width-in-plot-using-ggplot2

Comment: Thanks. It's a matter of preference really. I too used `scale_size_manual` but adding the `Highlight` column avoids having to type out all the possible values of `Fa.IVIVC` in the `values` argument, which is especially useful when you have more values.

Comment: I see what you mean. But the modification of the legend key associated with Fa.IVIVC (to show the thicker lines for just two elements therein) would have required typing out all the possible values of Fa.IVIVC, would it not?

Comment: It would appear so! I wasn't sure how to answer that part of your question.